# How to create python conda 64 bit environment in existing 32bit install?

Tags: python, anaconda, 32bit-64bit, development-environment, conda

I have a 32 bit installation of the Anaconda Python distribution.
I know how to create environments for different python versions.
What I need is to have a 64 bit version of python.

Is it possible to create a conda env with the 64 bit version?

Or do I have to reinstall anaconda or install a different version of anaconda and then switch the values of the PATH when I need the different versions?

I looked and searched the documentation, and the `conda create -h` help page did not find any mention of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, Anaconda installs into a self-contained directory (`<pwd>/anaconda3`). Since 64-bit and 32-bit builds of Python can not be mixed or converted into each other (in terms of the compiled Python binaries and libraries in `site-packages` or other `PYTHONPATH` location), you have to go with a second (64-bit) Anaconda installation in another directory.

If you have 32-bit code that needs to call 64-bit code, you have to rely subprocesses and pipes (or other IPC mechanisms). You probably have to be careful about your environment variables, e.g. `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` when doing so.

Comment: Hm, I didn't wanted to do this. I will need to change the `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable when changing versions, which is the same thing I wanted to avoid with conda.