# How to create a 64-bit python 2.7 environment in anaconda?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy, anaconda

I installed a python 3 anaconda file in windows and it's working fine.For a new project ,I am required to use python 2. So, according to the instructions given at official [anaconda blog](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html) ,I created a new python 2 environment using the following command.

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

But when I am trying to import numpy

```
 import numpy as np
```

Following error is raised.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

According to online post this error is raised because I am using a 64-bit system.So,From the suggestion of this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5) ,I used

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=
conda create -n py27_32 python=2.7
```

and created a new environment and activated it.But, I am getting the same error as above when I imported Numpy.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

So,64-bit python 2.7 is not installed.
Is there a way to install two anaconda files i.e anaconda python 2.7 64-bit version and anaconda python 3.5 64-bit version in the same windows computer?
If so,How to use different versions in jupyter notebook?
 Is it possible to install 64-bit python 2.7 environment?

MY System Details:
os : windows 7
processor : i3 intel processor.