# Anaconda in 64-bit but Spyder in 32-bit?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

The python interpreter in my conda environment is 64-bit but when I open up Spyder from the conda console, it automatically uses the 32-bit interpreter. I tried pointing the correct interpreter in Spyder but it says it's uncompatible

The specific error I get:
Either
1.Your IPython frontend and kernel versions are incompatible or
2.You don't have IPython installed in your external interpreter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple Python engines (32Bit/64bit and 2.7/3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have multiple Python versions installed in parallel? At least on Windows I have experienced some stubborn errors when this was the case. Can you comment some more on your setup? Specifically which Python distributions you use, which OS you are running and how your PYTHONPATH variable is configured.

#### edit

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5) which seems to cover your case.

Comment: Yeap, well I installed both the 32-bit and 64-bit Anacondas on Windows 7. It also looks like my PATH variable has the 32-bit python from Anaconda first before the 64-bit one.