# How can I have two different environments within Anaconda? (both Python 3.7, one 32bit and one 64bit)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

**What I need**

I require a 32bit conda environment, in addition to the current 64bit in my Anaconda distribution.

**What I've tried**

I've followed the step's within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33711433/11475846). However `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1` did not work in my case, I've verified this by checking the bit version after build. Comments in the answer and other [sources](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1744) suggest that it may have been removed.

I've also tried installing 32bit version [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) but I am having an issue changing environments because they both come under the same name `(base)`.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple Python engines (32Bit/64bit and 2.7/3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5) This should question should be consolidated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the 32-bit channel manually using the `--channel/-c` flag when using `conda create`.

You just need to supply the correct url for the channel and subdir you want to use.  The `--override-channels` flag prevents the 64-bit channels from being pulled in (shouldn't matter, but your never know).

```
conda create -n py32 python=3.7 -c https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32 --override-channels
conda activate py32
```

In your case, I would recommend installing the 64-bit version of Anaconda or Miniconda, then create the 32-bit environment.

Comment: Minor note: Technically, you don't need the full channel URL - the subdir is sufficient, e.g., `conda create -n py37 -c pkgs/main/win-32 python=3.7`

Comment: I think it would be better to write your novel answer up in [this older duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5), and then we should close this one as a duplicate.