# How to create a 32 bits exclusive conda env

Tags: python, conda

How can I create a exclusively 32 bits conda environment? I tried:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n py310_32 python=3.10.5
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follwing commands will successfully get a 32-bit python. I suppose the main problem is the environment variable. You know windows is this. :(

```
conda create -n py27_32
conda activate py27_32
conda config --env --set subdir win-32
conda install python=2.7
```

[image]

useful links:

1. [Using multiple Python engines (32Bit/64bit and 2.7/3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709391/using-multiple-python-engines-32bit-64bit-and-2-7-3-5)
2. [How can I have two different environments within Anaconda? (both Python 3.7, one 32bit and one 64bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010624/how-can-i-have-two-different-environments-within-anaconda-both-python-3-7-one)
3. https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1744

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. Though the conda info shows it'n in a win-32 platform, checking the bits trough this code:
import struct
print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
It still shows 64 bits, and the code that needs in 32 bits doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, and let me make future inspection.

Comment: I made it, and I will update the answer.