# Create 32 bits conda python environnement on a 64 bits system

Tags: python, linux, conda, version, 32bit-64bit

On my 64bits Fedora's machine, I would like to create a conda environment with the package python3.6  (or python2.7) for 32 bits architecture.

Is it possible to do that with a conda (64bits) installed on Fedora ?

Following [How to create a 32 bits exclusive conda env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72973933/how-to-create-a-32-bits-exclusive-conda-env)
I create the environement with these commands :

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n py27_32 python=2.7
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda activate py27_32
```

I do not get a 32 bit environment since the command
`python -c "import sys; print(sys. maxsize > 2**32)"` 
returns true.

It seems the previous link is dedicated to Windows machine. Is there a workaround for mac or linux system ?

Comment: See answer in marked duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918. The difference is that you need to specify a `subdir` of **linux-32** instead of **win-32**. There is no **osx-32** platform.