# pywin32-ctypes error in 32bit python 3.7 conda env

Tags: python-3.x, x86, conda, ctypes, pywin32

pyinstaller works on x64 conda envs just fine. but attempting to run pyinstaller in a 32bit conda env causes the error:

```
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install pywin32-ctypes.
```

i already have pywin32 installed. attempting to install again with `conda install -c anaconda pywin32` just tells me that pywin32 is already installed. and finally heres what happens when i try to import it in a python shell:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 31 2019, 14:57:46) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import win32api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Update: trying to `conda uninstall pywin32` returns:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
Package vs2015_runtime conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> sqlite[version='>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.28.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0']
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a']
Package vc conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
```

and trying to remove the 32 bit env using `conda env remove py3x86` causes:

`conda-env-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: py3x86`

Comment: How did you define a 32-bit env? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918? As for the `conda env remove`, you need to name the env you wish to remove, e.g., `conda env remove -n py3x86`.

Comment: i only used CONDA_FORCE_32BIT. following the link you gave me fixed the issue. thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/enthought/pywin32-ctypes pywin32-ctypes is a separate package from pywin32