# How to specify the architecture or platform for a new conda environment? (Apple Silicon)

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

Is there a way to specify the architecture/platform when creating a new conda environment?  Alternatively, how does conda detect its current architecture/platform when its run?

What I'm aiming to do is this:  I'm running on an Apple Silicon laptop. My pre-existing environments are running fine through Rosetta2, but I'd like to start experimenting with python running natively on Apple Silicon. `miniforge` provides a conda-forge repository with Apple Silicon builds, and I can tell conda to use the `conda-forge` channel when I create an environment. But I'm not seeing a way to specify that I'd like this to be an arm64 environment rather than an x86_64 environment, other than starting from miniforge's installer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should detect it from the OS.

Comment: I'm sure that's true, its detecting from the OS. But perhaps you could share precisely how its doing that, or where, or by what variable, or how that detection might be overridden?

Comment: You can try [setting subdir constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918) which is effectively how Conda segregates different platforms (win/osx/linux) and architectures (32/64).

Comment: @merv Thanks! That looks like its on the right path to an answer.  I think I'd have to combine it with the conda commands to specify a channel and not to use channel fallbacks. May work.  If you want to take your comment and turn it into a complete answer, I'll try it and select it as correct.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64 conda create -n native numpy -c conda-forge` will get you a `osx-arm64` native env.

To make it permanent, do,

```
conda activate native 
conda config --env --set subdir osx-arm64
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with `CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64 conda create -n py39_native python=3.9 -c conda-forge --override-channels`  I'm pretty sure you need the last bit.  If you want to add that to your answer I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: `--override-channels` is not strictly necessary. `-c conda-forge` is not needed if you have it already in your channels, but added it anyways.

Comment: This should be run in the new environment after creation: `conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64`  Otherwise future installs will revert to osx_64

Comment: @isuruf the `--override-channels` can safeguard against situations where users have other subdirs set in their configuration settings. Without it, the default `channel_priority` setting of `"flexible"`, leaves users open to Conda solving for packages from outside the specified subdir. Alternatively, using `"strict"` priority for channels can also work. So yeah, not strictly necessary, but it is a good defensive suggestion.

Comment: @Bob Thanks, this solved my problem.

Comment: How do you specify rosetta2? `osx-intel64`?

Comment: It should be `osx-64`.

Answer (score 9):

## How to configure python conda Environments for both `arm64` and `x86_64` on M1 Apple Silicon

Adding to the answers, it is possible to configure `conda` to use both  `osx-arm64`(arm64) and `osx-64`(x86_64) architectures.

I found adding `conda config --env --set subdir osx-arm64` changes the option globally which created issues for me. Some of my projects relied on python dependencies that were only supported in either one or the other architecture not both: specifically `tensorflow`.

### Install Xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```

### Install `miniforge3`

Install miniforge3 by downloading the shell script from here: https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge. Ensure you select arm64 (Apple Silicon) architecture. You may need to enable execution of the shell script with:

```
chmod +x Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

Then execute is with:

```
sh Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

### Add shortcuts to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`:

Add the following code to `~/.zshrc`.

The code will add two shortcut functions to create either an `osx-64` or `osx-arm64` conda environment.

```
# Create x86 conda environment
create_x86_conda_environment () {

  # example usage: create_x86_conda_environment myenv_x86 python=3.9
  CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n $@
  conda activate $1

}

# Create ARM conda environment
create_ARM_conda_environment () {

  # example usage: create_ARM_conda_environment myenv_x86 python=3.9
  CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64 conda create -n $@
  conda activate $1

}
```

### Create conda environment

Now to create a python `3.9.13` `osx-64`(x86_64) environment with the name `env_x86`:

```
create_x86_conda_environment env_x86 python=3.9.13
```

Alternatively for `osx-arm64` (arm64) environment:

```
create_ARM_conda_environment env_ARM python3.9.13
```

### Pip install packages

Once activated you can install packages accordingly. In my case I needed an `arm64` environment to install `tensorflow-macos`.

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos tensorflow-metal
```

Answer (score 1):

## Prerequisites

- Have Conda installed (anaconda / miniconda / miniforge3)
- Have a terminal (Terminal or iTerm app) running with rosetta (for x64)

## Add shortcut to create the environment

### what does this do?

- This function checks which architecture your current shell is using.

  - e.g. if you're running a terminal with rosetta, it will run with x86
- Base on the architecture, it will add a prefix to your environment name

  - x86: x86_{name}
  - arm64: arm64_{name}
- Creates the Environment & Activates it

### function

add the following function to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
create_conda_env () {
    arch_name="$(uname -m)"
    echo "Creating $arch_name environment"
    if [ "${arch_name}" = "x86_64" ]; then
        arch_type=osx-64
        env_prefix="x86_"
    elif [ "${arch_name}" = "arm64" ]; then
        arch_type=osx-arm64
        env_prefix="arm64_"
    else
        echo "Unknown architecture: $arch_name"
        exit -1
    fi
    echo "New environment name: $env_prefix$1"
    CONDA_SUBDIR=$arch_type conda create -n $env_prefix$@
    conda activate $env_prefix$1
}
```

### How to use?

- `create_conda_env {name} python={version} {aditional packages (optional)}`
- replace name, version and add any additional packages