# Install Python3.7 with Numpy natively on M1 Mac

Tags: python, numpy, apple-m1, pyenv

I need to Install Python3.7 to support Spark 2 on an M1 Mac.

I can get Python3.7 installed using pyenv, but when I try to install any of the data science libs, like numpy, I get failure: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'`

This seems to be related to libffi. Looking through the build logs for pyenv, I'm seeing this error:

```
.../Python-3.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/libffi_osx/include/fficonfig.h:51:2: error: "Unknown CPU type"
#error "Unknown CPU type"
 ^
1 error generated.

Python build finished successfully!
Failed to build these modules:
_ctypes               _decimal
```

Has anyone been able to successfully install 3.7 with numpy natively? I'm not looking for answers that involve Rosetta.

Comment: Make sure the pyenv build does in fact include ctypes. I'd imagine it's autodetecting things wrong...

Comment: Looks like it's failing to build ctypes. will post logs

Comment: Yeah, based on that error I think Python 3.7 just doesn't support the M1 without some manual patching to make it understand the cpu it's working with...

Answer (score 0):

Use **miniconda** to install things: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228696/9423009).

Miniconda is an open source version of the conda package/environment manager, as an alternative to pyenv + brew.

It will install ARM native versions of python by default, as well as native versions of modules.  This definitely include ARM native numpy.

I've quite sucessfully installed native python 3.7-3.10 and native numpy without any problems at all.  (In fact ARM native versions of almost every package I use).

With conda you use conda to install packages, not pip.

So to install numpy you do `conda install numpy` in the environment you're in.

Comment: Not super famiiar with conda, but was able to find an installer through Miniforge. However, it doesn't seem like python3.7 is available: "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - python=3.7"

Comment: did you try this command?  `conda create -n test_env python=3.7`.  That should create a new environment (called 'test_env') with python 3.7 as the python version it uses.  This works for me, and I checked the **conda-forge** repository (where miniforge conda will go to get packages) has python 3.5 and later available.

Comment: 'channels' are conda-speak for repositories.  by default miniforge conda should look in the conda-forge repository.  At a prompt, type 'conda search python`.  That should show you it's using the 'conda-forge' channel, and it will then list all the available versions of python you can install

Comment: very weird. I'm on the conda-forge channel, but not seeing anything before 3.8 when I search. same issue with the `conda create` command. It can't find 3.7

Comment: I've put a significant amount of time into trying to get 3.7 installed and I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: This is strange!!  When I search conda-forge I can find 3.7 (actually all versions back to 1.0.1!).

Comment: Some time later again... Are you sure you installed the native M1 Miniconda3, for which `conda info` says `platform: osx-arm64`? (Not `platform: osx-64` for Intel, which will be using Rosetta2.) For me, `conda search 'python[subdir=osx-arm64]'` and `... -c conda-forge` only find 3.8.x thru 3.10.x today. But for Intel `osx-64` I indeed get 1.0.1 thru 3.10.5, on conda-forge. (For `linux-aarch64` that is 2.7.15 thru 3.10.5 today.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the way I could fix it was to first create a conda environment with a new python version and then change the python version inside the activated environment with:

`conda install -c conda-forge python=3.7.8`