# Is it possible to create a conda environment with python compiled for a different architecture?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I have an M1 mac and would like to run multiple `conda` environments with python copiled for different architectures.

I have been using Anaconda to manage environments via `rosetta2` and it works perfectly.

However, I have recently tried installing ARM-compiled python using the guide in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534042/anaconda-and-upgrading-to-new-m1-mac) to install `miniconda` and that gave a pretty significant speed improvement in my quick test.

Using `rosetta2`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: a=np.linspace(1,100,10000)
   ...: a*=3.14
   ...: a+=a
   ...: a**2
   ...: 
   ...: 
32.7 µs ± 50.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Using native ARM python:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]:  %%timeit
   ...: a=np.linspace(1,100,10000)
   ...: a*=3.14
   ...: a+=a
   ...: a**2
   ...: 
   ...: 
22.3 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

My problem is that I have some code that will not run using the native ARM python as it uses packages that are not compatible (yet).

At the moment, I have both `anaconda` and `miniconda` installed in different locations and can switch between which version is called using `conda` by finding the path to their `conda` executable and running `absolute/path/to/executable/conda init`.

So what I would like to do is to create a `conda` environment that acts like the `miniconda` installation so that I can easily switch between environments if I require performance or compatibility. Is this possible?

Comment: See duplicate. One can use the `subdir` configuration option to lock in a particular environment to a given platform.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer. I also just found this answer which has a bit more info for anyone else that has the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65432861/17484663

Comment: I'd note that using `conda config --set --env subdir=osx-64` is better practice than setting the environment variable (`CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64`). The latter is the ultimate escalation in the order of overrides, so it's better to keep that in reserve.