# Cannot install Python 3.7 on osx-arm64

Tags: python, conda, conda-forge

I am trying to create a new environment with Python 3.7 using Conda like:

```bash
conda create -n qnn python=3.7
```

I got following errors:

```bash
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python==3.7

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

**Why is Python 3.7 apparently unavailable?**

---

### System Details

This is on an Apple Silicon (**osx-arm64**) machine running macOS.

Comment: What is your question? Have you used the suggested search option on anaconda.org or `conda search python` in the command line to see which versions are available?

Comment: support for arm64 is relatively new on conda-forge. I feel the problem is that you requested an older version of python and conda-forge does not support it. Moreover, I think as it is now this is a valid and clear question which does not merit closing.

Answer (score 76):

## No native builds available

Since Python 3.8 had been released for about a year when Apple Silicon hit the market, Python 3.7 builds for **osx-arm64** were never part of the regular build matrix for Conda Forge.

### Workaround: Emulate

Immediate alternatives for using 3.7 on Apple Silicon systems would be to emulate x86_64 with [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861) or use a container system, e.g., Docker.

#### Creating **osx-64** environments

Similar to [what one does for running **win-32** environments on x86_64 machines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918), one can create **osx-64** environments like

```bash
## create empty environment
conda create -n py37

## activate
conda activate py37

## use x86_64 architecture channel(s)
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64

## install python, numpy, etc. (add more packages here...)
conda install python=3.7 numpy
```

> ⚠️ Important Note: Be sure to always activate this environment before installing packages. Otherwise, the default CONDA_SUBDIR value (**osx-arm64**) may be active and could result in mixing architectures in the same environment.

Note that MacOS will automatically recognize the architecture and run through Rosetta ([once installed](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861)) - one need not do anything special.

#### YAML

With a YAML environment definition, one can use the `CONDA_SUBDIR` environment variable to temporarily set the platform while creating the environment. Again, one still should set the environment-specific `subdir` option immediately after creation.

```bash
## create environment from YAML
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda env create -n py37 -f py37.yaml

## activate
conda activate py37

## use x86_64 architecture channel(s)
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

---

### Requesting native build

Longer term, you could [try requesting](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues) that the `python-feedstock` include a 3.7 build for **osx-arm64**. However, 3.7.12 (Sept. 2021) was technically the final feature release, and it has now entered the maintenance-only phase (see [PEP 537](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0537/)). Also, other packages that build Python-version-specific variants would not be built for **osx-arm64**, so even if one had `python=3.7`, the packages wouldn't be there (at least not through Conda). Basically, I wouldn't bet on anyone taking this up.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!
I used `conda config --env --set subdir osx-64` before `conda create -n demo python=3.7`.

Comment: @shihs that means subdir was set for another environment - that is not correct. It must be set for the intended target environment. You should unset it in the original environment it was set in.

Comment: But why it could work? On the other hand, after the command `conda config --env --set subdir osx-64`, `python 3.7` shows in `conda search python` list. I thought this means python3.7 is available for the environment?

Comment: @shihs that sets the subdir for the current environment, and Conda still uses that configuration setting as long as it is active, despite running `conda create` for a new environment. The next time you try using `conda install` in the environment, Conda will try to installing everything as **osx-64**, whereas in the new environment it will default back to **osx-arm64**.

Comment: This worked, but a critical step is to make sure you've installed Rosetta 2, especially before attempting to run `conda install ...`. You can do that with `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861

Comment: `conda config --env --set subdir osx-arm64` in case you need to switch back to ARM architecture.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is the best strategy, but running

`CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda`

worked for my use case.

Comment: Yes, that is the "emulate x86_64" option.

Answer (score 0):

At this point we cannot actually install "faiss-gpu" in Mac OS with Silicon chips. This is because "faiss-gpu" is currently supported only with the below python versions, and the minimum python version needed to run for Mac OS with Silicon chip is python 3.8 as for now

```
Python :: 2.7
Python :: 3.5
Python :: 3.6
Python :: 3.7
```

This should help :)