# How do I download tensorflow-probability=0.11.1 with conda on mac M1?

Tags: python, macos, conda

I am trying to download a list of packages from a requirements.txt file on python using VSC and the M1 mac. I made a conda environment and tried to download the packages from the file but I  the error

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

I added many channels to my environment already: here is the ones I have so far:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/matsci/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/matsci/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/abinit/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/abinit/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

I was able to download tensorflow-probability but the version is 0.7, when I need 0.11.1, in which I get the error when I try to specify the version when installing via conda.

Here is a list of the other requirements/packages that haven't been able to download:

- jupyter-client
- jupyter-console
- jupyter-core
- sklearn
- ignnition
- importlib
- pickle5
- prometheus-client
- ipython-genutils

Note: I just took the version number out of the requirements.txt file because before that, basically none of them would work, and there is around 150 packages.

I'm wondering if this is a problem with M1 chip? Should I try running via Virtual Machine? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need exactly v0.11.1? There was a gap in Conda Forge builds between v0.8 and v0.12 (see [files](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow-probability/files)). This doesn't mean that there isn't also some M1 issue, but you shouldn't need a VM for that (e.g., see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure if i need exactly 0.11.1, but when I try downloading the newer versions, say 0.12.1, I get the same error