# How to install h3-py (from uber) with mamba?

Tags: python, conda, h3, mamba

I have recently switched to mamba as a package installer and am now trying to install h3-py into an environment. I have tried several ways, first using:

```
mamba install h3-py
```

but then it says

```
encountered problems while solving:
- nothing provides requested h3-py
```

If I try to install it with conda (conda install h3-py) i get a similar problem, and it returns:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - h3-py

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

I also tried both versions with -c conda-forge at the end, but get the same result (anyway conda-forge is already my main channel so I think that didn't change anything). Finally, I also tried installing it using pip, and again I get a similar response:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h3-py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for h3-py
```

The weird thing is that I've already installed h3 and h3pandas in a different environment (where I don't use mamba), so I don't understand why suddenly it can't find it... does anyone know how to fix this? I am using a MacBook Pro M1 Max and Miniforge3.

**EDIT**

In the end, I could install it using 'pip install h3' (instead of h3-py), but I was still wondering why I can't install it through mamba / conda-forge, since it says in the documenttion that it can be installed through forge: h3geo.org/docs/installation. However, merv clarified that in his answer below.

Comment: Actually I could install it using 'pip install h3' now, but I am still wondering why I can't install it through mamba / conda-forge, since it says in the documenttion that it can be installed through forge: https://h3geo.org/docs/installation

Comment: How exactly did you "*switch to mamba as a package installer*"? Installing a new Mambaforge installation? or by using `conda install -n base mamba`?

Comment: @merv The latter, so I just created a new environment, installed mamba, and then use mamba to install any other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Conda Forge [`h3-py` feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/h3-py-feedstock) is not yet building a version for the **osx-arm64** platform. [Auto-migration failed](https://github.com/conda-forge/h3-py-feedstock/pull/32), and [a manual workaround attempt](https://github.com/conda-forge/h3-py-feedstock/pull/34) seems to have stalled out. Anyone is welcome to contribute a PR to get it going.

To clarify, this has nothing to do with Mamba vs Conda - it's all about the platform. Perhaps by "*installing `mamba`*", OP means they installed a native (**osx-arm64**) Mambaforge distribution, versus a previous non-native **osx-64** installation.

Note that even with a **osx-arm64** base, one can still create **osx-64** environments, for example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918).

Comment: Okay thanks, then installing through pip seems to be the easiest option for now.