# conda python=3.7 not available on current channels

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I'm trying to set up a conda environment with python=3.7, but I'm getting a `PackagesNotFoundError`.

Is there a way to fix this error? For a python package, I could use pip in the conda environment. How would I got about installing another version of python itself?

Here's the command I used:

```
conda create --name mlpipeline python=3.7
```

Comment: More details needed. Adding output from `conda info` could be helpful. If this is on an **osx-arm64** platform, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918.

Comment: It’s the osx-arm64 issue. Thanks for pointing that out, I was not aware of it.