# Install a specific version of PyTorch on M1 chip arm64

Tags: macos, pip, pytorch, conda, apple-m1

I would like to install `torch==1.0.0` and `torchvision==0.2.1` on my Mac `macOS-12.5.1-arm64-arm-64bit` in a conda environment (`python 3.9`).

I referred to the PyTorch documentation: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v100

using pip :

```
(first) user@Users-MacBook-Air first-order-model % pip install torch==1.0.0 torchvision==0.2.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that met the torch==1.0.0 requirement (from versions: 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.0.0
```

or conda :

```
(first) user@Users-MacBook-Air first-order-model % conda install pytorch==1.0.0 torchvision==0.2.1 -c pytorch                 
Collect the package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Resolution environment: failed with initial resolution frozen. Retry with a flexible solution.
Collect package metadata (repodata.json): done
Resolution environment: initial frozen resolution failed. Retry with a flexible solution.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available in the current channels:

  - pytorch==1.0.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for other channels that may provide the conda package you are looking for, go to
you are looking for, go to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Do you know if this is possible? I don't think I've seen these versions available for arm64 here https://anaconda.org/soumith/pytorch/files .

Comment: You may have to build PyTorch from source

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain you will have to build from source. The Apple M1 came out in November 2020, but PyTorch 1.0 was released in May 2018. See the instructions on building form source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source (current master branch) (and here are the instructions for version 1.0.0: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v1.0.0#from-source)

Comment: @jkr they should be able to emulate. I.e., create an **osx-64** environment similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918