# packageNotFound when trying to install web3.py

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, web3py, conda-forge

I have multiple issues installing packages with having both Python and Anaconda installed. I have now got a clean install of anaconda and previous PIP installations removed.

I am unable to install web3.py still, when installing via the Anaconda environment / VScode I receive this error:

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> - web3
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/mamba/osx-arm64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/mamba/noarch
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
> you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I can see it is available but receiving this message. Would really appreciate any insight.

I was expecting to install without issue via `$`

```
conda install -c conda-forge web3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda Forge does not default (yet) to building packages for **osx-arm64** platform. Instead, users must request an **osx-arm64** build by adding it to the migration list via a Pull Request (see [documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#apple-silicon-builds)). This [has now been done for `web3`](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/pull/3825), but will take time to get approved and processed.

In the meantime, alternatives are:

1. Install from PyPI.
2. Emulate an **osx-64** environment using `CONDA_SUBDIR` environment variable. Similar procedure as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918).