# ResolvePackageNotFound on python dependency when building conda environment from config file

Tags: python, conda

I am working on an old project and I am trying to build a conda environment based on a config file.
It used to work well few months ago but now I run into some issues, here is my file

```
name: proj1
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - matplotlib
    - tensorflow
    - tensorflow-probability
```

Now if I run `conda env create -f conda_env.yml` I get the error :

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - python=3.7
```

Why is that ? I've set up many conda environments this way but it is the first time I run into this

Thanks a lot

Comment: What platform? E.g., **osx-arm64** doesn't have `python=3.7` https://stackoverflow.com/q/70205633/570918

Comment: I am on a macOS M2 chip

Comment: You were right, I changed to python=3.8 and it worked. However now I can't install tensorflow anymore. I have this error message : 
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: The duplicate has directions for emulating x86_64. If that doesn't work, then please ask a new question.