# Unable to install a package in conda (not found)

Tags: macos, package, conda, arm64, miniconda

I am trying to install a conda package named [astromatic-source-extractor](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/astromatic-source-extractor) from the conda-forge channel. I have a MacBook Pro with arm64 architechture.

The first problem I encounter is that conda is not finding it. I already tried setting the configuration for the priority of the channels to strict or true. Not working. This is what happens when I search for the package:

```
(base) diegozamora@Diegos-MacBook-Pro Downloads % conda search -c conda-forge astromatic-source-extractor -vvv
    DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(233): verbosity set to 3
    Loading channels: ...working... TRACE conda.gateways.disk.test:file_path_is_writable(22): checking path is writable /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/urls.txt
    DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(297): package cache directory '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs' writable: True
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(351): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.json. Timeout in 2380 sec
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(491): found pickle file /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.q
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(360): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(99): Using CondaRepoInterface
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(351): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/a850f475.json. Timeout in 2383 sec
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(491): found pickle file /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/a850f475.q
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(360): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(99): Using CondaRepoInterface
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(360): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.json
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(99): Using CondaRepoInterface
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(360): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.json
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(99): Using CondaRepoInterface
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(126): 
    >>GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
    > User-Agent: conda/23.3.1 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
    > Accept: */*
    > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    > Connection: keep-alive
    > If-Modified-Since: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 21:27:22 GMT
    > If-None-Match: W/"bd18071599942dd824e1ec40e9d10873"

    <<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
    < Age: 1058231
    < Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
    < CF-Cache-Status: HIT
    < CF-RAY: 7c9896c11c13d726-SCL
    < Date: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:32:55 GMT
    < ETag: "bd18071599942dd824e1ec40e9d10873"
    < Expires: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:33:25 GMT
    < Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 21:27:22 GMT
    < Server: cloudflare
    < Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=gKr.fY7PRCVLe596IrO4yjtLSBKeiVW1eqenf7837PA-1684459975-0-AZMQQY2fuHNd4/fwmTwZbylLZuPQQtI7VKi60K52DenRWysEZm88rWhcmV7PGGHVm6g7WxjjYuik83C13llKn88=; path=/; expires=Fri, 19-May-23 02:02:55 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    < Vary: Accept-Encoding
    < x-amz-id-2: LUhtxUoC03bhnlt8zsv3Fif4funme2PzT2P0M9tXTvllYWQgfd4YcIMpDQyx80uf49NFhRyJ9Bo=
    < x-amz-request-id: YEW5C8YGBA3C67Z8
    < x-amz-version-id: qq74F8wZiM.BcRfcrAyp1UmHfwCjHyAg
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Elapsed: 00:00.111116


    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(383): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(126): 
    >>GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
    > User-Agent: conda/23.3.1 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
    > Accept: */*
    > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    > Connection: keep-alive
    > If-Modified-Since: Wed, 17 May 2023 21:35:40 GMT
    > If-None-Match: W/"3488de0d78dad973c60bbb0f24a38f14"

    <<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
    < Age: 100507
    < Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
    < CF-Cache-Status: HIT
    < CF-RAY: 7c9896c11f68d772-SCL
    < Date: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:32:55 GMT
    < ETag: "3488de0d78dad973c60bbb0f24a38f14"
    < Expires: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:33:25 GMT
    < Last-Modified: Wed, 17 May 2023 21:35:40 GMT
    < Server: cloudflare
    < Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=zxc8p06PxMi7UhyQhTGEPujlHs_gSjAWHh7NS.EwPto-1684459975-0-Ac5l6tHWzwV4KRkS5lJjXYKL+rmWQuyuMEUJXLgWZw2eFgJaHOuVUQuGtVyh9MIA5O0dNGR0mzSguInBuefx8H4=; path=/; expires=Fri, 19-May-23 02:02:55 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    < Vary: Accept-Encoding
    < x-amz-id-2: ubXYJDEKD9BRidJJFIzto4Er3dv+It9Ky7KZZlmTD/Nsc3ir4bduLQQ3ZcaUHiTnywdcRYHd7ZY=
    < x-amz-request-id: 1FAKKDACK2G6DNVP
    < x-amz-version-id: 7GUqP3YzueALlI0ZRo5MW6v2lyV60Fzf
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Elapsed: 00:00.115345


    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(383): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(491): found pickle file /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.q
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(126): 
    >>GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
    > User-Agent: conda/23.3.1 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
    > Accept: */*
    > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    > Connection: keep-alive
    > If-Modified-Since: Thu, 18 May 2023 21:35:34 GMT
    > If-None-Match: W/"d314883c17682e06011d8c63ac105396"

    <<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
    < Age: 11788
    < Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
    < CF-Cache-Status: HIT
    < CF-RAY: 7c9896c11d466f26-SCL
    < Date: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:32:55 GMT
    < ETag: "d314883c17682e06011d8c63ac105396"
    < Expires: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:33:25 GMT
    < Last-Modified: Thu, 18 May 2023 21:35:34 GMT
    < Server: cloudflare
    < Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=1oZjq5CsM3le0fyPSy5_XxNIFQExwcJEHFoy53WJjmI-1684459975-0-Ad2N+Ew0OQvps5SZY/7jXjGVFvTwbLh4IUAIo2WNzxSaTn4/+nEhbWIt/1PHn2ZzHxV1sJCfOU12Ectb3xa6CYE=; path=/; expires=Fri, 19-May-23 02:02:55 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    < Vary: Accept-Encoding
    < x-amz-id-2: LSyh2cWzOcHZfOipZQ5qErQ2rdo4vnM4NKrtQxBuF+8XKNO/Gbzrdm9tcNBU7TmKsPiwA4VBWtU=
    < x-amz-request-id: ENXYE9M49Z8ST2S9
    < x-amz-version-id: p92eT1RVHwP.JsATSqLDb_Hjhwscw3DT
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Elapsed: 00:00.116665


    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(383): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(491): found pickle file /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.q
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(491): found pickle file /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.q
    DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
    DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(126): 
    >>GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
    > User-Agent: conda/23.3.1 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
    > Accept: */*
    > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    > Connection: keep-alive
    > If-Modified-Since: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 15:33:23 GMT
    > If-None-Match: W/"93476d5e7aa8d3f8bc0c04afafc94d26"

    <<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
    < Age: 553674
    < Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
    < CF-Cache-Status: HIT
    < CF-RAY: 7c9896c118032df2-SCL
    < Date: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:32:55 GMT
    < ETag: "93476d5e7aa8d3f8bc0c04afafc94d26"
    < Expires: Fri, 19 May 2023 01:33:25 GMT
    < Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 15:33:23 GMT
    < Server: cloudflare
    < Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=d3NqonYvG9cxDDbVTjK6_nmYn4JF89ObRNAHIcHmIgU-1684459975-0-AclN+3jLa1inxNsy4BHPWrXrOYT9w2gbSql5OXAHzKVtvqamq6wf8EWDnuh5Y2bqWaKTlVZUHfOlQRDIPoUaybE=; path=/; expires=Fri, 19-May-23 02:02:55 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    < Vary: Accept-Encoding
    < x-amz-id-2: tNROl2BJzHu4gTfEFW8Y3y7RjLlvtIR4zlLppdLmI1svsPRaJ2P0hYItNiPAd57q1s2AiumDf5g=
    < x-amz-request-id: B7EXP4830Y53B5C2
    < x-amz-version-id: gruUyeXEAuhL5g34laDjUOasClLQRFQz
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Elapsed: 00:00.132181


    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(383): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
    DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(491): found pickle file /Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.q
    done
    No match found for: astromatic-source-extractor. Search: *astromatic-source-extractor*
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1132, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 122, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_search.py", line 86, in execute
        raise PackagesNotFoundError((str(spec),), channels_urls)
    conda.exceptions.PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

      - astromatic-source-extractor
```

Then I tried downloading and installing directly from the file (`conda install astromatic-source-extractor-2.28.0-hca6ac57_1.conda`). It installed succesfully, but when I tried to execute the software I got this:

```
dyld[5707]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/libcfitsio.10.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/bin/source-extractor'
  Reason: tried: '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      sex
```

so I installed the package missing: `conda install cfitsio`. It reported that it `astromatric-source-extractor` was causing inconsistency, but it proceeded. Then after trying to execute source-extractor again:

```
dyld[5805]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/libcfitsio.10.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/bin/source-extractor'
  Reason: tried: '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64))), '/Users/diegozamora/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64))), '/usr/local/lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcfitsio.10.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      sex
```

This time the file is found, but it has an incompatible architecture. I guess it makes sense because if I go to the index.json file from the package I need to install it says

```
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "build": "h49ae774_0",
  "build_number": 0,
  "depends": [
    "fftw",
    "liblapacke >=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0"
  ],
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "name": "astromatic-source-extractor",
  "platform": "osx",
  "subdir": "osx-64",
  "timestamp": 1570113827345,
  "version": "2.25.0"
}
```

However I know someone that has the same computer and installed the software using conda, so I makes no sense. What could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is for x64 and you have an environment set up for arm64. Mixing both will never work. I do not know what your colleague did (you could ask him, I can't), but he is most likely running an x64 python interpreter through rosetta.

With `conda` you can also set up an environment that runs an x64 version of python and looks at the x64 subdirs when installing packages. merv has created an easy guide in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/5012099) originally written to install a specific python version, but you can follow the steps for your case all the same:

```
## create empty environment (choose name as you wish)
conda create -n ase

## activate
conda activate ase

## use x86_64 architecture channel(s)
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64

## add conda-forge
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge

## install python, and your package. Add whatever else you need here
conda install python astromatic-source-extractor
```