# Open3D failing to install on Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, open3d

Beginner trying to tackle Open3D but I can't even begin when it fails to install on my Anaconda.

Currently on a Windows x64 using Anaconda environment (Python v3.10) with pip being latest version.

Please help, I'm very confused right now. Checked with http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/getting_started.html but nothing seems out of place.

Steps done:

- Open Anaconda Navigator
- make new environment with python 3.10.4 on it
- used `pip install open3d`, failed
- downloaded `.whl` file from github and then used `pip install open3d-0.17.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`, failed as well

Error Logs:

- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d (from versions: none)
- ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d
- ERROR: open3d-0.17.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

`python -m pip --version` gives

```
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\dienv\anaconda3\envs\Open3d\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

`python --version` gives

```
Python 3.10.4
```

and I have also tried `python -m pip install open3d`, which gives

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d
```

When I run just `python`, the first line in the console is

```
Python 3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 30 2022, 13:41:19) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Comment: can you verify `python -m pip --version` `python --version` and also try `python -m pip install open3d`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller pip is - `pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\dienv\anaconda3\envs\Open3d\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`.
python version is - `Python 3.10.4`.
attempt to install gives me - `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d (from versions: none)` and `ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d`.

Comment: can you post the first two lines that is printed when you just run `python` in the command line

Comment: @FlyingTeller `Python 3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 30 2022, 13:41:19) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: ah, you have a 32 bit anaconda installation. was that intentional?

Comment: @FlyingTeller nope, currently a student intern. the anaconda is pre-installed by company

Answer (score 1):

Your base anaconda installation appears to be 32 bit. I am assuming that your OS is 64 bit. You should probably ask your IT department to change anaconda to a 64 bit installation. It will make your life easier in the future.

Alternatively, you can try two approaches:

There seems to be a 32 bit compatible conda package, so you could, instead of `pip`, run

```
conda install -c open3d-admin open3d
```

Alternatively, you  you can try creating an environment that is 64 bit. For that, we have to change the subdir before installing anything like so (from [merv's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205633/cannot-install-python-3-7-on-osx-arm64/70219965#70219965)):

```
## create empty environment
conda create -n open3d

## activate
conda activate open3d

## use x86_64 architecture channel(s)
conda config --env --set subdir win-64

## install packages
conda install -c open3d-admin python  open3d #add all other packages here
```

I would go with the last approach.