# Attempting to install conda package and receiving error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, arcgis, esri

I'm attempting to install the arcgis conda package from esri using the following command:
conda install -c esri arcgis

It fails with the following error message:

```
github-image/arcgis-python-api [master] » conda install -c esri arcgis
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - arcgis

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I checked the anaconda.org repository and there appears to be an arcgis package located under the esri channel:

[image: repository]

Please note that this is on MacOS with Apple silicon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Anaconda Cloud does not have **osx-arm64** builds for that package. You can try installing an **osx-64** version and run it in emulation mode. This will need to be in a fresh environment, e.g.,

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n foo -c esri arcgis
```

This is a similar situation to users installing older versions of Python, so you may want to additionally read [Cannot install Python 3.7 on osx-arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70205633/570918).

Comment: Thanks - I was able to install it on an older Macbook Pro that runs on Intel silicon

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I found an compromising alternative through pip and installing an older version of the Python library.

```
pip install arcgis==1.8.*
```

Hope this helps a bit