# Cannot install R conda packages on Apple Mac M2

Tags: r, macos, anaconda, conda, apple-m2

I can't seem to install R conda packages although it is available on conda.

For example, [r-raster](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-raster);

```bash
$ mamba install -c conda-forge r-raster

Looking for: ['r-raster']

conda-forge/osx-arm64                                       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.11.*


Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
```

Non R packages seem to install fine. Am I missing something?

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20.0.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.5

conda 23.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `r-raster` builds for **osx-arm64** depend on `r-terra`, [which has unresolved issues building](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-terra-feedstock/pull/77). Until that is fixed, Conda Forge cannot provide `r-raster` for **osx-arm64**. I happen to be one of the maintainers on it, but simply don't have the time to spend on patching the autoconf script to supporting cross-compilation. If anyone wants to help get that build working, please send a PR.

In the meantime, one can also emulate **osx-64** environments, as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918). For example, something like

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n foo r-base=4.2 r-raster
```