# Not able to install catboost version 1.0.4 using conda

Tags: pip, conda, catboost

I was using catboost v1.0.4 in a Conda environment. Recently, I had to recreate the environment, then it is showing the folllowing error.

```bash
Error with conda install
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
- catboost=1.0.4

Error with pip install

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost==1.0.4 (from versions: 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost==1.0.4
```

I have tried various channels (`conda-forge`,`anaconda`). I am on Mac M1 Pro (Monterey 12.1). I have also tried using `pip install`, it also did not work.

How can I install `catboost=1.0.4` in a Conda environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda Forge only [started building `catboost` for **oxs-arm64**](https://github.com/conda-forge/catboost-feedstock/pull/97) since v1.1.1. You can try installing the **osx-64** version instead. See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918.