# Problems installing with conda under MacOS 14.1 M1

Tags: macos, conda, bioinformatics, apple-m1, bioconda

I am trying to install [bakta](https://github.com/oschwengers/bakta) on my MacBook Pro 14" with an M1 processor. When I run

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda bakta
```

I get the error:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/osx-arm64::__osx==14.1=0
  - feature:|@/osx-arm64::__osx==14.1=0

Your installed version is: 14.1
```

Can somebody help me understand what is going on? I think there is a problem with installing packages that `bakta` depends on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bioconda does not build for **osx-arm64**. Instead you must install from the **osx-64**, and macOS will run the software in emulation mode. That is, use:

```bash
## create a new environment
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n bakta_env -c conda-forge -c bioconda bakta
```

To safeguard against installing non-**osx-64** software in this environment, I recommend subsequently setting the `subdir` for the environment's configuration:

```bash
conda activate bakta_env
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918

Comment: Thanks! This worked well and is a very clear explanation