# Conda PackagesNotFoundError while trying to install keyboard

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

Trying to install keyboard module using conda, and when I inputted

**conda install -c conda-forge keyboard**

returned

**PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- keyboard

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
- defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.**

I tried **conda config --append channels conda-forge** and then **conda install keyboard** and it still didn't work. I am working in a conda environment and other packages like opencv install correctly.

Am on MacOS if that's important

Comment: Are you sure that `keyboard` is a package that can be installed with conda?  Where did you learn about this package?  Are you sure that is the correct package name?  Are you sure it is installed with `conda`, and not some other way like `pip`?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, it has a Conda package: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keyboard

Answer (score 0):

In command promt/control panel run the following:

```bash
conda update conda
conda update --all
conda install -c conda-forge keyboard
conda install keyboard=0.13.5
conda activate [ENVIROMENT NAME]
```

then try `pip install`,
if this doesn't help, try to uninstall `anaconda navigator` and reinstall it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That package is currently built for **osx-64**, but not for **osx-arm64** (what most macOS users have now).

When encountering this, first thing to do is tell Conda Forge that you'd like this built for **osx-arm64** since this is done by request only (not a default). There are directions here: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#apple-silicon-builds.

In the meantime, macOS users can always fallback to emulating with **osx-64** packages. There are details on that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918).